# Use of 'self' in property access 'model' before super.init initializes self super.init(brand: brand, model: model)

Tags: swift

I'm following this tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/160728/object-oriented-programming-swift

...and trying to make some personal adjustments to the code to see if I'm able to understand some core concepts on my own.

I end up with the following code :

```
class Instrument {

var brand: String
var model: String

init(brand: String, model: String) {

    self.brand = brand
    self.model = model

}

func tune() {

    print("\(model) tuned !")
}

func play() {

    print("\(model) plays an improvised melody")

}

func perform() {

    print(tune())
    print(play())
}

}
```

And this subclass :

```
class Piano: Instrument {

var hasPedals: Bool

init(hasPedals: Bool ) {

    self.hasPedals = hasPedals
    super.init(brand: brand, model: model)

}

}
```

At this point, I have the following error message :

> Playground execution failed:
>
> error: Object oriented programming.playground:28:41: error: use of
>   'self' in property access 'model' before super.init initializes self
>           super.init(brand: brand, model: model)
>                                           ^
>
> error: Object oriented programming.playground:28:27: error: use of
>   'self' in property access 'brand' before super.init initializes self
>           super.init(brand: brand, model: model)

I have the feeling that this is a super obvious mistake, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

---

Edit : Thanks a lot you guys for the super clean answers. It make a lot of sens to me now !

If I understand it correclty, even when you are using a custom init method in a subclass,  you need to initialize all the stored properties (from both superclass and subclass) right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the superclass `init` method to initialize part of your subclass. However, before you have initialized it, you passed an uninitialized variable. Simply add those variables into the parameter of the `Piano`:

```
init(hasPedals: Bool, brand: String, model: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at this:

```
init(hasPedals: Bool ) {

    self.hasPedals = hasPedals
    super.init(brand: brand, model: model)

}
```

What are `brand` and `model` that you are passing to the super initializer? Where are they defined? If you meant `self.brand` and `self.model`, nope, you can't use them. They haven't been initialised!

Without knowing what you really want your Piano's initializer to be like, I can't answer the question accurately, but one way of fixing this is to add `brand` and `model` parameters:

```
init(hasPedals: Bool, brand: String, model: String) {

    self.hasPedals = hasPedals
    super.init(brand: brand, model: model)

}
```

Now `brand` and `model` refer to the parameters.